# conflicting dependency error on installing new software in Ecllipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, xtend

I am trying to start work with Xtend language using Eclipse IDE, and when i am installing new software
    in it by adding below url
    http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/

```
Then i am getting these errors

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Xtend SDK 2.3.0.v201206120633 (org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group 2.3.0.v201206120633)
  Software being installed: Xtext UI 2.4.1.v201304180855 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.group 2.4.1.v201304180855)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Xtext UI 1.0.2.v201102150722 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 1.0.2.v201102150722)
    Xtext UI 2.4.0.v201303201134 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.4.0.v201303201134)
    Xtext UI 2.6.1.v201406120726 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.6.1.v201406120726)
    Xtext UI 2.5.2.v201402120812 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.5.2.v201402120812)
    Xtext UI 2.1.1.v201111141332 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.1.1.v201111141332)
    Xtext UI 2.3.0.v201206120633 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.3.0.v201206120633)
    Xtext UI 2.3.1.v201208210947 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.3.1.v201208210947)
    Xtext UI 2.4.1.v201304180855 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.4.1.v201304180855)
    Xtext UI 2.4.2.v201306120542 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.4.2.v201306120542)
    Xtext UI 2.2.1.v201112130541 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.2.1.v201112130541)
    Xtext UI 2.5.1.v201402030714 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.5.1.v201402030714)
    Xtext UI 2.0.1.v201108020636 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.0.1.v201108020636)
    Xtext UI 2.5.4.v201404100756 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.5.4.v201404100756)
    Xtext UI 2.4.3.v201309030823 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.4.3.v201309030823)
    Xtext UI 2.5.3.v201402240820 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.5.3.v201402240820)
    Xtext UI 2.6.0.v201405210727 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.6.0.v201405210727)
    Xtext UI 2.5.0.v201312110906 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar 2.5.0.v201312110906)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Xtend SDK 2.3.0.v201206120633 (org.eclipse.xtend.sdk.feature.group 2.3.0.v201206120633)
    To: org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.group [2.3.0.v201206120633]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Xtext UI 2.3.0.v201206120633 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.group 2.3.0.v201206120633)
    To: org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar [2.3.0.v201206120633]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Xtext UI 2.4.1.v201304180855 (org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.group 2.4.1.v201304180855)
    To: org.eclipse.xtext.ui.feature.jar [2.4.1.v201304180855]

Please help me to resolve this issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Xtend SDK from the category Xtend {version} and complete the wizard by clicking the Next button until you can click Finish.

If you have selected multiple items, first `deselect all`. Then choose the lastest `Xtend-2.6.1` version. Worked for me.

[image: Selecting Xtend]
[image: Install Details for Xtend]

[More installation help](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/download.html).

Comment: thanks , i have installed that but still i am not able to use xtend, as i am getting error on "def"
**
public class Sample {
 def void main(String[] args){
        //Main Method
       }
}**

Comment: have you followed the installation help? runtime/maven? link above.

Comment: sorry i cant upvote cz of low score!
http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/download.html
I am not using maven, and i am confused from 
"Download Runtime Libraries" section of the above link i cant understand that where i have to put the downloaded file, can u plz help